# Getting overloaded method ~> with alternatives Akka broadcast

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to broadcast incoming Source[ByteString, Any] to 2 different flows and then fan-in(zip) the output. However I'm getting error "overloaded method ~> with alternatives".

```
val byteStringSource: Source[ByteString, Any] = Source.fromIterator(() => (1 to 10).map(i => ByteString(s"Element $i")).iterator)

  val incrementer = Flow[String].map{ x =>
    x
  }
  val multiplier = Flow[String].map{ x =>
    x
  }

  val output = Sink.foreach[(Type1, Type2)] { n1 =>
    println(s"First obj is ${(n1._1.toString)} & second obj is ${n1._2.toString}")
  }

  val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(
    GraphDSL.create() {implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[String](2))
      val zip = builder.add(Zip[Type1, Type2])//fan-in operator

      byteStringSource ~> broadcast
      broadcast.out(0) ~> incrementer ~> zip.in0
      broadcast.out(1) ~> multiplier ~> zip.in1

      zip.out ~> output
      ClosedShape
    }
  )
  graph.run()
```

How do I get around with this issue?

Comment: At which line do you get the error and what is the complete error message?

Answer (score 1):

Your source is of type `ByteString` but the broadcast element is of type `String`, so the `~>` operator won't be applicable.

For your simple example you can remove ByteString and just use plain strings. If your real situation uses more complex types, you can map the original source into the type that the broadcast will accept, so something like

```
val theSource = byteStringSource.map(byteString => ...)
```

and just use `theSource` in your GraphDSL.